# Python list ways to select objects

Tags: python

I have three lists: `[A, B, C]`, `[1]`, `[x,y]`.

How to generate the following with python:

`[A,1,x]`, `[A,1,y]`, `[B,1,x]`, `[B,1,y]`, `[C,1,x]`, `[C,1,y]`

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Z = [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1], ['x', 'y']]

import itertools
for element in itertools.product(*Z):
    print(element)
```

Result:

```
('A', 1, 'x')
('A', 1, 'y')
('B', 1, 'x')
('B', 1, 'y')
('C', 1, 'x')
('C', 1, 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using a list comprehension:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
l2 = [1]
l3 = ['x', 'y']

product = [
    [a, b, c]
    for a in l1
    for b in l2
    for c in l3
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product([A, B, C], [1, 2], [x,y])) 
# provided A, B, C, x, y are variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

To start:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = ['A','B']
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> list(product(a, b))
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)]
```

And:

```
>>> a = ['A','B','C']
>>> b = [1]
>>> c = ['x', 'y']
>>> list(product(a,b,c))
[('A', 1, 'x'), ('A', 1, 'y'), ('B', 1, 'x'), ('B', 1, 'y'), ('C', 1, 'x'), ('C', 1, 'y')]
```

That is that you want, but please try to search a bit more before to post a question.